# Maintaining order in a list in $AC^0$ in $O(1)$ time

Tags: ds.data-structures

The order maintenance problem (or "maintaining order in a list") is to support the operations:

- `singleton`: creates a list with one item, returns a pointer to it
- `insertAfter`: given a pointer to an item, inserts a new item after it, returning a pointer to the new item
- `delete`: given a pointer to an item, removes it from its list
- `minPointer`: given two pointers to items in the same list, returns the one closer to the front of the list

I am aware of three solutions to this problem that perform all operations in $O(1)$ amortized time. They all use multiplication.

- [Athanasios K. Tsakalidis: Maintaining order in a generalized linked list](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00289142)
- [Dietz, P., D. Sleator, Two algorithms for maintaining order in a list](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/maintaining-order.html)
- [Michael A. Bender, Richard Cole, Erik D. Demaine, Martin Farach-Colton, and Jack Zito, “Two Simplified Algorithms for Maintaining Order in a List”](http://erikdemaine.org/papers/DietzSleator_ESA2002/)

Can order be maintained in a list in $O(1)$ amortized time without using any arithmetic operations not in $AC^0$?

Comment: Multiplication has only recently (since Pentium III) been in $AC^0$. Can we include solutions which use multiplication?

Comment: I don't think that's correct. First, I don't think multiplication is in $AC^0$. Second, I don't think particular machines, like the Pentium III you mention, have anything to do with the question of whether multiplication is in $AC^0$. Finally, as demonstrated in the question, I obviously am aware of several multiplication-based algorithms for this problem, so adding more in a new "answer" does not in any way improve things.

Comment: Found where I read about this; it was about Pentium 4 not III; and didn't implement multiplication instead worked around it with a new instruction from that processor: M. Thorup, ‘On AC0 Implementations of Fusion Trees and Atomic Heaps’, in Proceedings of the Fourteenth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, Philadelphia, PA, USA, 2003, pp. 699–707.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes!

Use a two-level structure as discussed at the end of Section 2 of the Dietz and Sleator paper. For the top structure, use a scapegoat tree. By using a balance factor that can be implemented in $AC^0$ (like $2$), we get the result.

See also [exercise 8.12 from open data structures](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-cpp/8_2_Discussion_Exercises.html) and [Roura's "A new method for balancing binary search trees"](http://users-cs.au.dk/gerth/alcom-ft/TR/ALCOMFT-TR-01-167.ps.gz).